# Monte Carlo simulation on forming polygons from broken sticks

Tags: python, polygon, montecarlo

Given a broken stick of n pieces, I want to do Monte Carlo simulation to find the probability that **there exist** k pieces (3<=k<=n) that can form a k-gon. Assuming that the broken pieces are ordered, it should be enough to check if the groups of k consecutive segments respect the triangle inequality.

The following code agrees with an exact formula for k=3, but for k>3, the simulation always outputs a result slightly smaller compared with an exact formula, except if I set k=n (e.g. for k=4, n=5, the simulation gives about 0.828, but the formula gives 7/8=0.875).

I checked what the code does manually by printing the verification done and it was doing exactly what I want.
Do you see anything that might be causing a problem?

```
def broken(k,n,nb_iter): # kgon from n piece broken stick with 3<=k<=n
  compteur=0

  for i in range(nb_iter): # nbr iterations
    L=[0,1] # points (ends)
    M=[] # segments
    x = np.random.random(n-1) # n-1 points at random

    for i in x: # add the points to L
      L.append(i)
      L.sort()

    for i in range(n): # range(n)
      M.append(L[i+1]-L[i]) # make segments
      M.sort()

    for i in range(n-k+1): # inequalities to check
      if M[k+i-1] <= sum(M[i:k+i-1]):
        compteur=compteur+1
        break
  return (compteur,compteur/nb_iter)
```